# Qual a diferença na instalação de pacote com npm install e npm install --save?

Tags: npm

Qual seria a diferença entre a instalação de um pacote qualquer com o comando `npm install` e o comando `npm install --save`?

Supondo que necessite instalar um dado pacote denominado **xyz**, se executar o comando:

```
npm install xyz --save
```

Com o comando acima o pacote será instalado e o arquivo **package.json** terá o pacote como dependência para o projeto.

Agora se executar o comando:

```
npm install xyz
```

O que acontece?

Comment: Desde a versão 5 do npm (2017), a opção `--save` não é mais necessária, pois agora é o comportamento *default*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808